# is $(P,Q)= \sum_{k=0}^2 P(k)Q(k)$ orthonormal or orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthonormal

i don't know how to answer this textbook question and to define if it's orthonormal or orthogonal.

the question is: $(P,Q)= \sum_{k=0}^2 P(k)Q(k)$ is defined to be an inner product space in $R_3[x]$, and let $P_1=1$ $P_2=x-1$ $P_3=x^2-2x+\frac{1}{3}$. are ${(P_1,P_2,P_3)}$ orthonormal or orthogonal?

since Q(k) is not given, i don't know how to approach it at all. for it to be orthogonal, the inner product should equal to 0 and each different element in it should be perpendicular to each other, and for it to be orthonormal the length of the unit vector should be 1.

but i don't know how to determine if it's just orthogonal or aso orthonormal. would like your help with it please.

Comment: The title of the post is not the question you are supposed to answer; you are asked to show if $P_1,P_2,P_3$ are orthonormal or orthogonal. To check orthogonality, you need to check if $(P_1,P_2)=(P_1,P_3)=(P_2,P_3)=0$ holds. To check orthonormality, you need to check if $(P_1,P_1)=(P_2,P_2)=(P_3,P_3)=1$ holds.

Comment: i got that it is only orthogonal (each element against himself not equals to 1). thank you very much!